# Reading kernel command line arguments in driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

In order to read the kernel boot command line parameters, should the driver read the sysfs entry `/proc/cmdline` or is there any other simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `core_param` or `module_param` from `include/linux/moduleparam.h`